# How to use Array.prototype.map() with then() for connection.end()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have an error `TypeError: cars.map(...).then is not a function`. I want terminate connection when update the color.

```
cars.map(function (item, i) {
    if (item.color === 'red') {
        updateColor(item.id)
    }
}).then(() => connection.end())
```

Comment: `map` works with Array only. Did you initialize `cars` as an array?  again `then` also not work with `map`

Comment: You are chaining `then()` to `map()`, you just can chain `then()` to a function that returns a promise

Comment: I'm not sure how these two are connected. If you have a `cars` array already, then you don't need a connection, so you can simply terminate before the `.map` call and nothing should change. Or you can call `cars.map(/* ... */); connection.end();` which is guaranteed to run after the mapping operation.

Answer (score 11):

**This answer only applies in case `updateColor` is asynchronous and indeed returns a `Promise` object.**

`.map` returns an array of something, not a `Promise`. What you can do, is building an array of `Promise` using `.map` and then resolve them all using `Promise.all` and then deal with the result.

The following code will execute all `updateColor`, wait until they are done and then stop the connection.

```
Promise.all(cars.map((item, i) => {
    if (item.color === 'red') {
      return updateColor(item.id);
    }

    return false;
  }))
  .then(() => connection.end())
```

---

Using `async/await` instead of `Promises`

```
  await Promise.all(cars.map((item) => {
        if (item.color === 'red') {
          return updateColor(item.id);
        }

        return false;
      }));

   connection.end();
```

---

using `reduce` instead of `map`

```
await Promise.all(cars.reduce((tmp, x) => (x.color === 'red' ? [
  ...tmp,

  updateColor(x.id),
] : tmp), []));

connection.end();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of issues there:

1. There's no reason to use `map` when you aren't using the array it creates. To loop through the array, use `forEach` or [any of several other mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).
2. `map` is a fully synchronous function. To do something after it, just...do the thing after it.
3. `then` is a method of promises (well, *thenable*). `map` returns an array, not a promise.

So:

```
for (const item of cars) {
    if (item.color === 'red') {
        updateColor(item.id)
    }
};
connection.end();
```

***If*** `updateColor` does its work asynchronously **and** returns a promise, then see [Grégory NEUT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58318973/157247).